# Can I charge multiple SLA batteries at once like this?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, battery-charging

Simple question from a beginner. I 'drew' a schematic diagram to show my idea of how I could charge multiple SLA batteries with a single charger. Would this work if I solder the wires together as shown?

[image]

If this approach does not work, do you have any other recommendations for how to charge multiple SLA batteries with one pair of wires? I don't want to charge one, unhook, charge another, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That should work, if the charger is designed to charge lead-acid batteries, and can deliver a reasonable current relative to the capacity of the batteries.  A 1 or 2 Amp charger would probably be OK with up to 24 Ah of batteries, but may not be of much use with 100 Ah.

A simple 12 volt DC power supply wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah it's a wall adapter charger unit. I think our total Ah will be around 30-40. Understanding the physics here, if I solder them together as shown are they all bound to have the same voltage then? Also are there any safety concerns of which I should be aware? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: An ordinary 12 volt wall-wart power supply won't work - you must use something designed to charge lead-acid batteries.  The time taken to charge the batteries will depend on the current rating of the charger, and the Ah rating of the batteries, and how deeply they were discharged.

Answer (score -1):

This should really not be done as you risk damaging the batteries as there is no balancing between them. A proper bms should be used instead.